# Get invoice price when increasing quantity of subscription item in Stripe

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm trying to retrieve the prorated invoice price from stripe when the customer increases the quantity of a subscription item. For example, the basic plan is $10 and the option to add an extra 2000 api calls per month is $4.99. If the customers wants 4000 more api calls per month then they would be increasing the subscription items quantity for the $4.99 price from 1 to 2. The price will vary per say the customer decided to increase the quantity half way through the billing period. In this case they should be charged $2.49. The next billing period should then charge the $4.99 at the start.

After attempting to retrieve the upcoming invoices using `stripe.invoices.retrieveUpcoming({...})` It returns the wrong price each time. Its always more than it needs to be. Seems to be 2 times the base plan of $10 and only one of the $4.99 prices. This is my code from my backend (its an array element in an array of routes.):

```
  {
        url: '/invoice-amount',
        type: eRequestType.GET,
        handler: async (req, res) => {
            const { proration_date, subscription, price, customer } = JSON.parse(req.headers["invoice-details"])
            try {
                const sub = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(subscription)
                let siID = null, oldQuantity = null
                for (let si of sub.items.data) { if (si.price.id === price) { siID = si.id; oldQuantity = si.quantity } }
                if(!siID) {
                    const invoice = await stripe.invoices.retrieveUpcoming({
                        customer,
                        subscription_items: [{price}],
                        // subscription_proration_date: proration_date
                    })
                    return res.json({"amount": invoice.amount_due})
                } 
                else {
                    const invoice = await stripe.invoices.retrieveUpcoming({
                        // customer,
                        subscription,
                        subscription_items: [{ id: siID, price, quantity: oldQuantity + 1}],
                        subscription_proration_date: proration_date
                    })
                    return res.json({"amount": invoice.amount_due})
                }
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
                res.json({ "error": error.message })
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling that route from the front end looks like this:

```
async function fetchInvoiceAmount() {
            return axios.get('/invoice-amount', {
                headers: {
                    "invoice-details": JSON.stringify({
                        "proration_date": Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
                        "subscription": props.subId,
                        "price": ePrices.EXTRA_API_CALLS,
                        "customer": props.user.cust_id
                    })
                }
            })
        }
```

When I test This code with a customer subscribed to my monthly plan at $10 per month and they are not paying for then extra api calls the route returns `{"amount": 499}` or $4.99. This seems to be correct. After reviewing the stripe docs, it mentions not passing in a subscription id and only passing in `subscription_items` will return the amount if the item was added to the subscription. But like from earlier, what if the customer signs up half way through the month? It should not be returning `{"amount": 499}` but should be returning `{"amount": 249}`. The real problem arises when the customer already has at least one subscription item to the $4.99 price. The route then returns `{"amount": 2497}`. When analyzing this output, I believe that its increasing the base price of $10 to a quantity of 2 and not touching the api price of $4.99.

How do I get this to return the prorated amount for only the one quantity increase of the api call price?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is preview the change in quantity, you should be able to do it like this:

```
                const invoice = await stripe.invoices.retrieveUpcoming({
                    // customer,
                    subscription,
                    subscription_items: [{ id: siID, quantity: oldQuantity + 1}],
                    subscription_proration_date: proration_date
                })
```